# Замена h4 title woocommerce на свой

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

как заменить в товарах wooocommerce заголовок h4 class
на свой?может быть можно это сделать через хуки?

Comment: В каком месте h4? в зависимости от места можно изменить хуками.

Comment: в списке товаров

Comment: Напишите нормальный вопрос, чтобы не нужно было додумывать остальное

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы изменить тайтл товаров в цикле вы можете использовать следующий код:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'my_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 10 );
function my_woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title() {
    echo '<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product_title"><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h2>';
}
```

Comment: https://apphone.ru/

на главной список товаров
а как убрать старый заголовок h4?там два заголовка стало

Comment: remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10 );

Comment: Если это не убирает заголовок, значит он уже переопределен где-то в теме, ищите в теме

Comment: А можете подсказать как поменять заголовок h3 в виджетах на свой?
apphone.ru/iphone

Comment: Можете использовать фильтр widget_title

Comment: а код можете написать если не сложно?спасибо

Comment: Используется плагин Advanced AJAX Product Filters for WooCommerce, как с помощью хука сменить h3 в виджетах?

Comment: я уже ответил тебе, читай документацию